# Handling multiple RestTemplate instances for multiple hosts

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, basic-authentication, resttemplate, apache-httpcomponents

I am building out a web service which proxies and does some slight manipulation of HTTP requests.  I'm handling requests going to multiple hosts of the same type but of which I don't know of until run time (I consume a web service that gives the host IPs).  Each host that I interact with has different credentials (Basic-Auth, fetched from a non-local database, credentials change periodically).  The way I handle things today is pretty naive.  For every request, I am constructing a new RestTemplate like so:

```
public static RestOperations getRestOperations(int timeout, String username, String password)
{
    RequestConfig requestConfig = RequestConfig.custom().setConnectionRequestTimeout(timeout).setConnectTimeout(timeout).setSocketTimeout(timeout).build();
    CredentialsProvider credsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
    credsProvider.setCredentials(AuthScope.ANY, new UsernamePasswordCredentials(username, password));
    CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.custom()
        .setDefaultCredentialsProvider(credsProvider)
        .setDefaultRequestConfig(requestConfig)
        .build();
    ClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(
        httpclient);
    return new RestTemplate(requestFactory);
}
```

So each Controller method always starts out with:

```
UsernamePassword userPass = credentialService.getCredentials(request.getRemoteHost())
RestOperations restOps = getRestOperations(userPass.getUser(), userPass.getPass(), TIMEOUT_IN_MILLIS);
```

It seems to me that since I'm constructing a new RestTemplate with each request that any previous connections that have been made between my server and the host are not being reused.

Is this the case?  If so, then it seems I will need some sort of RestTemplateFactory which can cache RestTemplate instances based on the host IP address so that connections can be reused.  However if I do that, then I need some mechanism that makes sure that the credentials haven't changed and to check and update credentials if they do change.  Is there a better solution?

Comment: You should not create a new RestTemplate with every request, because doing so can be expensive.

Comment: You could implement some kind of "session" functionality, keeping one RestTemplate per session.

Comment: I think I may have a possible problem with that approach, which is that a user will more than likely interact with multiple hosts in a single session.  I guess I could have a Map on each session and a RestTemplate per host per session though.